# create dynamic records from time stamps

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Id  Date        Time                        Location    leadHourDiff
3   2017-01-01  2017-01-01 13:00:00.000     Boston      2
15  2017-01-01  2017-01-01 13:00:00.000     Philly      1
16  2017-01-01  2017-01-01 15:00:00.000     Philly      1
```

and i would like dynamically create the hour records between Time and (Time + leadHourDiff)

so the end result would be:

```
Date        Time                        Location    
2017-01-01  2017-01-01 13:00:00.000     Boston      --main record
2017-01-01  2017-01-01 14:00:00.000     Boston      --new record
2017-01-01  2017-01-01 15:00:00.000     Boston      --new record

2017-01-01  2017-01-01 13:00:00.000     Philly      --main record
2017-01-01  2017-01-01 14:00:00.000     Philly      --new record
2017-01-01  2017-01-01 15:00:00.000     Philly      --main record
2017-01-01  2017-01-01 16:00:00.000     Philly      --new record
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing this. Also, forgot to mention that I only wanted the missing time values. That was an tpyo on my part. Here's the whole solution

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders(
    Id          int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,[Time]     datetime
    ,[Location] varchar(20) 
    ,OrderAmt   int
)

INSERT INTO #Orders
SELECT '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 'Boston', 23  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 12:00:00', 'Boston', 31  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 13:00:00', 'Boston', 45  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 16:00:00', 'Boston', 45  UNION ALL ---15
SELECT '2017-01-01 17:00:00', 'Boston', 67  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 18:00:00', 'Boston', 89  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 19:00:00', 'Boston', 90  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 20:00:00', 'Boston', 123 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 21:00:00', 'Boston', 145 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 22:00:00', 'Boston', 156 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 23:00:00', 'Boston', 145 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 'Boston', 167 UNION ALL

SELECT '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 'Philly', 23  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 12:00:00', 'Philly', 31  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 13:00:00', 'Philly', 45  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 15:00:00', 'Philly', 45  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 17:00:00', 'Philly', 67  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 18:00:00', 'Philly', 89  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 19:00:00', 'Philly', 90  UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 20:00:00', 'Philly', 123 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 21:00:00', 'Philly', 145 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 22:00:00', 'Philly', 156 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 23:00:00', 'Philly', 145 UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 'Philly', 167


;WITH HourDiff AS (                     
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Id
            ,CAST([Time] AS date) AS [Date]
            ,[Time]
            ,[Location] 
            ,COALESCE(lead(DATEPART(HOUR, [Time])) OVER(PARTITION BY [Location], CAST([Time] AS date) ORDER BY [Time] ASC ) - DATEPART(HOUR, [Time]),1)-1 AS leadHourDiff
        FROM #Orders    
    ) t1
    WHERE t1.leadHourDiff <> 0  
)
, CTE AS (

    SELECT 
        Location
        ,DATEADD(HOUR, leadHourDiff, [Time]) AS missingTime     
    FROM HourDiff

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Location
        ,DATEADD(HOUR, leadHourDiff - 1, [Time]) AS missingTime     
    FROM HourDiff
    WHERE Time < DATEADD(HOUR, leadHourDiff - 1, [Time])
)

SELECT
    Location
    ,CAST(missingTime AS time) AS missingTime
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Location, missingTime

DROP TABLE #Orders
```

Final result:

```
Location    missingTime
Boston      14:00:00.000
Boston      15:00:00.000
Philly      14:00:00.000
Philly      16:00:00.000
```

**UPDATE:**

here's an update..the final CTE was not working properly when i add new data for new york

new data for new york:

```
SELECT '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 'New York', 23    UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-01-01 20:00:00', 'New York', 31    UNION ALL
```

new final CTE:

```
, CTE AS (

    SELECT 
        Location
        ,DATEADD(HOUR, leadHourDiff, [Time]) AS missingTime
        ,[Time]     
        ,leadHourDiff
    FROM HourDiff

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Location
        ,DATEADD(HOUR, leadHourDiff - 1 , [Time]) AS missingTime    
        ,[Time]     
        ,leadHourDiff - 1   
    FROM CTE
    WHERE leadHourDiff >= 0
    AND Time < DATEADD(HOUR, leadHourDiff - 1, [Time])  
)
```

Final result:

```
Location    missingTime
Boston      14:00:00.0000000
Boston      15:00:00.0000000
New York    12:00:00.0000000
New York    13:00:00.0000000
New York    14:00:00.0000000
New York    15:00:00.0000000
New York    16:00:00.0000000
New York    17:00:00.0000000
New York    18:00:00.0000000
New York    19:00:00.0000000
Philly      14:00:00.0000000
Philly      16:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a numbers table (This can be generated with a recursive cte) and join the leadHourDiff column on to that.

```
with numbers(num) as (select 0
                      union all
                      select num+1 from numbers where num < 100 --change this as needed
                     ) 
select t.*,dateadd(hour,n.num,t.datetime_col) as new_datetime
from tbl t
join numbers n on t.leadHourDiff >= n.num
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, date, time, Location, leadHourDiff
      from t
      union all
      select id, date, dateadd(hour, 1, time), location, leadHourDiff - 1
      from cte
      where leadHourDiff >= 0
     )
select date, time, Location
from cte
order by location, date, time;
```